# How to get en editable ITextBuffer from an IDifferenceViewer's LeftView?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-2019

I want to be able to edit the ITextBuffer of the left ITextView (`LeftView` property) coming from an IDifferenceViewer, but as soon as it is constructed, the LeftView is readonly when `IsReadOnly()` is called. How can I allow the LeftView's ITextBuffer to be editable?

```
var diffService = (IVsDifferenceService)_serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(SVsDifferenceService));

//roles don't seem to do anything...
string roles = null; //$"{PredefinedTextViewRoles.Editable},{PredefinedTextViewRoles.PrimaryDocument},{PredefinedTextViewRoles.Document},{PredefinedTextViewRoles.Interactive},DIFF";
var frame = diffService.OpenComparisonWindow2(filePath1, filePath2,
    $"Your version vs Other version",
    filePath1 + Environment.NewLine + filePath2,
    filePath1,
    filePath2, null, null, 0);
var diffViewer = GetDiffViewer(frame);
diffViewer.LeftView.TextBuffer.IsReadOnly(0, false); // true!
```

```
static IDifferenceViewer GetDiffViewer(IVsWindowFrame frame) {
            ThreadHelper.ThrowIfNotOnUIThread();
            return ErrorHandler.Succeeded(frame.GetProperty((int)__VSFPROPID.VSFPROPID_DocView, out object docView))
                ? (docView as IVsDifferenceCodeWindow)?.DifferenceViewer : null;
}
```

Comment: Does the LeftTextView you mean refers to [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.text.differencing.idifferenceviewer.leftview?view=visualstudiosdk-2019). In IdifferenceViewer Interface, there seem to only exist LeftText.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT I updated the post to be more clear -- the property name is `LeftView`

Comment: Hi brianc, I've trying to involve someone more experienced in it to help research it. Please be patient for the response.